# Trouble with java snippets

Tags: java, code-snippets

```
    public class GenericWorldLoader implements WorldLoader {
    @Override
    public LoginResult checkLogin(PlayerDetails pd) {
        Player player = null;
        int code = 2;
        File f = new File("data/savedGames/" + NameUtils.formatNameForProtocol(pd.getName()) + ".dat.gz");
        if(f.exists()) {
            try {
                InputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
                String name = Streams.readRS2String(is);
                String pass = Streams.readRS2String(is);
                if(!name.equals(NameUtils.formatName(pd.getName()))) {
                    code = 3;
                }
                if(!pass.equals(pd.getPassword())) {
                    code = 3;
                }
            } catch(IOException ex) {
                code = 11;
            }
        }
        if(code == 2) {
            player = new Player(pd);
        }
        return new LoginResult(code, player);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean savePlayer(Player player) {
        try {
            OutputStream os = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data/savedGames/" + NameUtils.formatNameForProtocol(player.getName()) + ".dat.gz"));
            IoBuffer buf = IoBuffer.allocate(1024);
            buf.setAutoExpand(true);
            player.serialize(buf);
            buf.flip();
            byte[] data = new byte[buf.limit()];
            buf.get(data);
            os.write(data);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            return true;
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean loadPlayer(Player player) {
        try {
            File f = new File("data/savedGames/" + NameUtils.formatNameForProtocol(player.getName()) + ".dat.gz");
            InputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            IoBuffer buf = IoBuffer.allocate(1024);
            buf.setAutoExpand(true);
            while(true) {
                byte[] temp = new byte[1024];
                int read = is.read(temp, 0, temp.length);
                if(read == -1) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    buf.put(temp, 0, read);
                }
            }
            buf.flip();
            player.deserialize(buf);
            return true;
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Yeah so... My problem is that this seems to save 'something' in really complex and hard to read way(binary) and I'd rather have it as an .txt, in easily readable format. how to convert?

EDIT: I'm not using Apache Mina, so what should I replace

```
IoBuffer buf = IoBuffer.allocate(1024);
buf.setAutoExpand(true);"
```

with?

Answer (score 0):

`checkLogin()` obviously checks whether the specified login has matching data present and whether the password is correct.

`savePlayer()` method saves the player.

`loadPlayer()` loads it again.

The data format used is [gzip](http://www.gzip.org/) ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip)) and it is written as a stream of [serialized](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) data. If you want to make it more readable, you might want to overload (or just use it, if it is good) `toString()` method of `Player` class and to write `player.toString()` into a new text file using e.g. [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) wrapped around a [File Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html):

```
String playerName = NameUtils.formatNameForProtocol(player.getName());
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(playerName + ".txt"));
writer.write(player.toString());
writer.close();
```